# Disable/Remove printfs from library

Tags: gcc, embedded, printf

we have a vendor provided library which has printfs turned on. This is a major annoyance, and we would like to turn it off or disable it someway.

Is there a way to completely disable printfs for everything in this library without access to library source code? We would like to have printfs in other part of the application.

We are using gcc toolchain for an embedded (sh4) platform.

Thanks!

Comment: What is use case of library? If one isolated call, then you may redirect stdout before it and then return it back after it. If you have thousands of calls, then this overhead is too much

Comment: Just one place. How to redirect stdout to null?

Comment: requires some code, will write separate answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hack the library to call a dummy wrapper function instead of the real `printf`. Here's how you'd do it (assuming the library is distributed as a static library):

1. Create a file called `wrap_printf.c` with the following contents:

   ```
   int __wrap_printf(const char *fmt, ...) {
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Compile the wrapper:

   ```
   gcc wrap_printf.c -c -o wrap_printf.o
   ```
3. Unpack the library:

   ```
   mkdir libobj; cd libobj; ar x libvendor.a
   ```
4. Relink each vendor object file to use the wrapper:

   ```
   for obj in libobj/*.o; do ld --wrap=printf $obj -r -o $obj
   ```
5. Rebuild the library, including the wrapper:

   ```
   ar rcs libvendor_noprintf.a wrap_printf.o libobj/*.o
   ```
6. Link your program against the new library as usual

   ```
   gcc program.o -lvendor_noprintf -o prog
   ```

Comment: We use gcc for sh architecture on Windows. I tried this, but id didn't work. Everything is ok until step 5, in step 5 I get an archive which is smaller than the input archive (2 MB vs 2,5 MB). When I try to compile it, the system complains about the missing functions :(

Comment: Ok. I fixed this thanks to your help. In the fifth step, I didn't call the command you called, but

ar cr libvendor.a libobj\*.o wrap_printf.o

This didn't create a new library, but replaced all files from the old library with .o files with printf removed. Now it works :D

Answer (score 0):

In particular case when you have only one place where library is used, you may use `freopen` to redirect stdout. Try this sample on Linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
  printf("This goes to screen\n");
  freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
  printf("This goes to nowhere");
  freopen("/dev/tty", "w", stdout);
  printf("This goes to screen again\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Drawback of this method is that it is platform-dependent. On windows you must use `"NUL"` and `"CON"` devices instead of `"/dev/null"` and `"/dev/tty"`

Comment: We are not using linux, but some proprietary OS (called OS21). I tried this but it didn't work :(

Comment: You just need to know symbolic names of null and stdout devices. I don't know what OS21 is, if there is no documentation on its device names, then agree, this will not work.

Comment: I tried everything I can remember but it didn't work. Maybe the os doesn't support reopening standard devices)...